# How do I hide part of the H2 text with css?

Tags: html, css

I know this is not a good practice but is there a way I can hide part of the H2 text with CSS? Here is what I have.

HTML:

```
   <div class="twocol-box1 superflex-content-6-12">    
    <h2 data-content="My - Text&amp;nbsp;<span style=&quot;float:right;&quot;>May 16, 2022</span>">My - Text&nbsp;<span style="float:right;">May 16, 2022</span></h2>
```

CSS:

```
.twocol-box1 h2, .twocol-box2 h2:before {
    content: "My - ";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
}

.twocol-box1 h2, .twocol-box2 h2 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Updated with Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/awm2rs7n/

In my above example, I want to hide "My -"

Expected Output: Text May 16, 2022

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Am I allowed to use js?

Comment: You need to use JS but CSS can be used in hacky way too.

Comment: I tried using javascript but it doesn't work. Problem is the content is coming from cms & somehow its not recognizing js. So I really need to hack this with css. Thanks.

Comment: If it's rendered in the DOM, it will always work with JS. You need to post the JS you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Using the background color to cover the text:

```css
#hideme {
  position: relative;
}

#hideme:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: white;
  content: ""
}
```

```html
<div class="mytext">
<h2 id="hideme">My - Text<span style="float:right;">May 16, 2022</span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou. I have updated my question: <div class="mytext">
  <h2 class="hidepartial">My - Text<span style="float:right;">May 16, 2022</span></h2>
  
</div> Also, please note that I am unable to manipulate my HTML since its coming from cms

Comment: See my updated answer and let me know if that works better for you. It's not pretty but you're limited on options here.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no great way to do this in CSS. There is a hacky way of using the `:before` pseudo-element with `content` to target the text you want to hide. I'd suggest using `js` to physically remove the text.

If your text is always the same it will work. Essentially this solution just finds the text and masks it.

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
}

h2:before {
  content: "My - ";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="mytext">
  <h2>My - Text<span style="float:right;">May 16, 2022</span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Hate to do this but Well I could see the text with the dark mode extension :)

Comment: @innocent How about on this [fiddle?](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/xy3zrdm8/)

Comment: Thankyou. I tried both the methods. But somehow, the class ignores content: "My - ". It adds white background to entire H2 text. Is there a reason it would be ignoring content? I asl marked it as important but still doesn't work.

Comment: @magicsinger try adding `top: 0;` and `left: 0;` to the `:before`.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome & Edge (chromium based)

Comment: @magicsinger send me a fiddle of the code you are trying to use where it's covering the entire `h2` and I'll fix it.

Comment: Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/awm2rs7n/

Answer (score 0):

you can add another span give it a class then display none.

```css
span.hideme {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="mytext">
<h2 class="hidepartial">
<span class="hideme">.My - </span>Text<span style="float:right;">May 16, 2022</span></h2>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am unable to change HTML in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use span to wrap the part of h2 and add a class to select the span in CSS and then you can apply the any CSS properties you want . For your question below is the code

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mytext">
  <h2 class="hidepartial"><span class="hide">My - </span> Text<span style="float:right;">May 16, 2022</span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I am unable to alter HTML since its comes from cms. Can only change css.